# Sscanf to scan a line with columns

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read a file line by line and transfer it to another file.
This is the format for the first file-

```
1001:Brendes:Howard:0:750.92
```

So I got thru most of the line but the decimal at the end is giving me trouble.
Here is what I have until now. I declared `salesAmount` as `double` and tried it with `%f`, `%lf`, `%d`, `%lf[^n]`, `%lf[^\0]` but nothing works.

```
while(fgets(oneline, 200 ,fPointer)!= NULL){
    sscanf(oneline,"%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d[^:]:%lf", &salesNum, lastName, firstName, &salesLevel, &salesAmount);
    printf("%d , %s , %s , %d , %lf \n", salesNum, lastName, firstName, salesLevel, salesAmount);
}
```

This is the normal Output:

```
1001 , Brendes , Howard , 0 , -0.380207

1002 , Jervis , Michael , 0 , -0.380207

1003 , Chen , Jessica , 1 , -0.380207

1004 , Ding , Sheng , 1 , -0.380207
```

So what do I have to do to make my code read the last decimal properly?

Comment: Why you didn't use fscanf()?

Comment: Show declaration of `salesNum,lastName,firstName,salesLevel,salesAmount`  for a good complete answer.

Comment: @TryinHard Using `fgets()` is much better at coping with error handing and presenting maintainable code than `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d[^:]:%lf"` is wrong (a typo).  Format likely should be
`"%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf"`.

For the future: if code checked the return value of `sscanf()`, which was certainly `4`, OP would likely have discovered this.

---

Untested candidate improvement:

```
int salesNum;
char lastName[100];
char firstName[50];
int salesLevel;
double salesAmount;

char oneline[200];
while(fgets(oneline, sizeof oneline, fPointer) != NULL) {
  char sentinel;
  if (5 != sscanf(oneline,"%d : %99[^:]: %49[^:]:%d :%lf %c",
      &salesNum, lastName, firstName, &salesLevel, &salesAmount, &sentinel)) break;
  printf("%d , '%s' , '%s' , %d , %lf\n",  
      salesNum, lastName, firstName, salesLevel, salesAmount);
}
```

Comment: `sscanf()` returns the number of successfully scanned fields (variables).  In this code, if it does not return `5`, something is wrong.  Various `sscanf()` details are web-available.

Comment: This is the POSIX specification for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).